# boost::any maps with char[]

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, casting, dictionary

In my class, I have char data[1000]. I want to be able to have a map to have a map of key type string mapped to any type of data I want.

In my driver, I want to be able to get out the values from my map. Essentially using my map to be able to hold all the data for my class so that I am not restricted to the data defined in the header for the class but can add and remove data at runtime.

For example class definition:

```
public:
    void populateMap()
    {
     classMap["imgData"] = data;
    };
private:
    map<string,boost::any> classMap;
    char data[1000];
```

driver:

```
int main(){
   myClass test; 
   map<string,boost::any> myMap;
   test.populateMap()//populates map with the char data
   myMap = test.getMap();
   char myData[1000] = boost::any_cast<char*>(myMap["imgData"]); //runtime error
}
```

When I do this, I get runtime casting errors. I'm not well versed in char[definite_size] versus char *. Can someone direct me in where my problem is? I have not seen very many examples of people storing char array's in  maps. What is the proper way to store char[definite_size] into the map? What does the casting look like to get it back out of the map (boost::any requires you cast to the proper type when pulling out of the map)

Comment: Try using `std::array<char, 1000>` everywhere instead of this silly C stuff.

Comment: I tried doing that but it is very slow to store the array in the map. I've tried storing the array's address in the map but then how do I get it back out? Note that I am using boost::array which works the same as std::array but std::array no longer exists? Eventually, I need to convert the boost::array to char* anyway though.

Comment: If you just want to store a pointer, try either `std::unique_ptr<std::array<char, 1000>>(new std::array<char, 1000>)` or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[1000])`. The latter can be accessed as an array directly.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ and in C, there is a difference between array types and pointer types, though the two are very closely related.  For example, in C and C++, the type of

```
int array[137];
```

is `int[137]`, not `int*`.  That said, when you use `array` in C, it decays into a pointer to the first element.  In C++, however, it is possible to get a reference to an array.  For example, this code is perfectly legal:

```
/* This function takes a reference to an array of 137 elements as a parameter! */
void MyFunction(int (&array)[137]) {
    /* ... */
}

int myArray[137];
MyFunction(myArray);
```

Here, the type of the argument to `MyFunction` is `int (&)[137]`, a reference to an array of 137 integers.

This comes up when using templates.  For example, if we have this template function:

```
template <typename T> void MyFunction(T& arg) {
    /* ... */
}

int myArray[137];
MyFunction(myArray);
```

Then the call to `MyFunction` will fill in that `arg` is `int[137]`, rather than `int*`, because the argument has type `int[137]`.

The reason this is a problem is (IIRC) that the `boost::any` type's assignment operator is a template that looks at the type of its argument and stores this information.  As a result, if you say

```
boost::any myAny;
int myArray[137];

myAny = myArray;
```

I *think* that this will have the `myAny` variable store an object of type `int[137]` rather than `int*`, because the pointer type doesn't decay.

To fix this, you should consider using the new `std::array` type to explicitly indicate that you have an array type being stored.  That way, you wouldn't ask for a pointer, but would instead try to pull out something like a `std::array<int, 137>`.  Alternatively, if you know for a fact that you're using a `char[1000]` as the stored type, you may be able to reengineer the program so that you don't use a `boost::any` here.  You could also consider using a `typedef` to export the default type being stored (here, `char[1000]`) so that you could cast to the proper type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just force the decay from a `char[1000]` into a `char*` with an explicit cast? That is, in `populateMap` do: `classMap["imgData"] = (char*)data`

Comment: @NicolBolas- That's a good point.  Actually, why doesn't the any type do that automatically?

Comment: Probably because the maintainers of Boost don't care enough to actually do it. Or because not that many people use `boost::any` that ever encounter such a problem.

Comment: @Nicol: I personally find the unary `operator+` to be a much nicer "decayer" than a cast: `anyobj = +data;`. :) This has the added benefit of being type agnostic and much less typing (especially when doing C++-style casts).

Comment: @Xeo: It's also a lot harder to tell what's going on. Say what you will about the verbosity, but `(char*)data` is pretty explicit about what is happening.